# Amazon EC2 instance - Play Framework connectivity

Tags: amazon-web-services, playframework, amazon-ec2, connection, port

I created an EC2 instance and added ALL TCP and UDP ports. ICMP also... Started my play application with both port 9000 and 80, neither worked out. The application starts, I can connect to it from the instance but I cannot connect to it from outside.

telnet instance_dns_name 9000 fails whereas telnet instance_dns_name 3389 works.

I don't know what I am missing. The same issue happened in Microsoft's Azure too. May it be about the region?

Comment: Does play bind to the IP 127.0.0.1 by default?

Comment: I don't know. It seems that it binds to this: [info] play - Application started (Prod)
[info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000

Comment: I installed apache webserver for 127.0.0.1. On the server calling the url: 127.0.0.1 works but still I cannot reach to it from outside...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One more important thing...

If you have Amazon EC2 instance of *Debian* or *Ubuntu* - by default, they do not have internal firewall (**iptables**)

On the other hand, *RedHat Enterprise* edition **DO HAVE** firewall and if you want to work properly, you can open the proper ports in *iptables* or disable *iptables* - your choice.

I prefer to disable completely *iptables* since you already have Amazon Security Groups that are with the same role as *iptables*.

Comment: how do you disable them?

Comment: Check out this url: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/turn-on-turn-off-firewall-in-linux/

Answer (score 3):

Did you open up the ports in both the AWS EC2 security group page AND either turn off your local firewall or open the necessary ports? You probably need to do both.

Comment: No, I don't have a firewall and here is my security group:                                                      Ports Protocol Source quick-start-1                   0-65535 tcp     0.0.0.0/0 
80 tcp 0.0.0.0/0 
3389 tcp 0.0.0.0/0 
9000 tcp 0.0.0.0/0 
0-65535 udp 0.0.0.0/0 
53 udp 0.0.0.0/0 
-1 icmp 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: The instance may have firewall. I'll check on that.

Comment: For future searches:
red-hat instances do have firewall. It's called "iptables". Turning it off for a session it as simple as:
sudo /etc/init.d/iptables stop

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that instances have firewall also. When I add inbound rule to windows server 2008 instance's firewall the problem resolved.

Comment: If someone goes to the trouble of answering your question correctly, it would be more appropriate to mark that persons answer as the correct one, rather than restating the answer that you were given and then marking your own answer correct.