# Amazon EC2: Can't access Play framework application

Tags: amazon-web-services, playframework, amazon-ec2

I have a RedHat Amazon EC2 machine. I've installed in this machine Play framework and created an example application calls **test**.

I've also opened the port 8080 to get requests from the outside world.

```
8080 (HTTP*)   0.0.0.0/0
```

If I'm executing the Play application (**test**) as follows:

```
play "run 8080"
```

I get the following:

```
--- (Running the application from SBT, auto-reloading is enabled) ---
[info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8080

(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)
```

When I'm trying to get access via the browser:

```
http://public-dns.com:8080
```

I get nothing.

Can someone tell me what I've forgot? Or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Redhat often has an internal firewall configured by default which also needs to have port 8080 opened.

Answer (score 0):

Similar question was asked and answered just recently here:

[Amazon EC2 instance - Play Framework connectivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16090022/amazon-ec2-instance-play-framework-connectivity)

most likely culprit is the internal firewall or the aws firewall - both need to be set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You will also have to change the internal firewall using iptables:

To allow connections to port 8080:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 8080 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
```